# Setting user offline not working, when the user closes the browser tab

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

In a page of my site is a list of some users, where a green ball shows if the user is online and a red ball if he is offline. I defined the `online()` and `offline()` PHP methods, that writes a value to a field in the database and that can be called from whithin a Javascript code. I wrote then a Javascript code, where I added an event listener to the `visibilitychange` event (the only one that really fires, when the user is reading a page of the site or switches to another page), and this all works fine. But if the user closes the browser tab, instead of switching to another one, the `visibilitychange` event is not fired and the user remains online. I tried to add an event listener to the `beforeunload` and `unload` events, but they are not fired when the user closes the tab, unless I call the `preventDefault()` method, that sometime works and sometimes not, but shows anyway the dialog box asking the user to confirm exiting the window, what I don't want he to do. And anyway it does not work always. So, how can I set the user offline, when he closes the browser tab?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

javascript is run only as long as the client is willing to do it. Dont't rely on that as the only way to get data.

An alternative strategy, and one that you can also use in addition to your own, is to record the last activity timestamp for each user and then consider them "offline" after a few minutes has passed.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I already thought about this solution and I already implemented it, but I was wondering whether it would be possible to update the value just when the user closes the tab.

Comment: I'm no expert, but if I were a browser developer I would *not* run any server-provided javascript code on a tab close.